# What's the difference between `element.removeEventLister` and `element = null`?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove `eventListener` when I call the destructor method manually.

I thought instead of calling `this.element.removeEventListener()`, assigning `null` to `this.element` would work.

But, it seems that the click event stays even after I call the destructor method manually.

Why is that? and what is the difference between these?

I appreciate if someone explains it!
Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/wj8z25hs/4/

## HTML

```
<button>Button</button>
```

## JavaScript

```
class X {
    constructor() {

    this.btn = document.querySelector('button');

    this.fn = function() { 
        console.log('click');
    };

        this.btn.addEventListener('click', this.fn);

    }

    destructor() {

        // This works.
        // this.btn.removeEventListener('click', this.fn);

        // This does not work. why?
        this.btn = null;
    }
}

let x = new X();
x.destructor();
```

Comment: assigning null to `element` doesn't remove it from the DOM

Comment: Because `this.btn` is just a reference to the element-- you're simply reassigning the value of the property.  If I write down your address on a piece of paper and then rip up the piece of paper, your house wouldn't be destroyed.

Comment: @Alexander Nied That explanation is so good!! I got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a variable that references an object (an element is an object), that variable is essentially only a pointer to a *location in memory* where the object is located. (that's why objects are *referenced* and not *copied* when assigned to new variables) So, if you assign null to the variable, the object does not get destroyed - it only removes the reference that that particular variable has to the object.

The object in memory will only actually be destroyed when it gets (automatically) GC'd, when nothing has a reference to it anymore. In your case, the DOM still has a reference to the element.

If you want to remove the element from the DOM, which will remove the listener as well, use `this.btn.remove()`.

Comment: This part `So, if you assign null to the variable, the object does not get destroyed - it only removes the reference that that particular variable has to the object` is actually not relevant to the OP's issue.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the problem OP was running into, though? He was thinking that `this.btn = null;` would destroy the object.

Comment: instead of `this.btn.remove()`, `this.btn.parentNode.removeChild(this.btn);` is correct in vanilla JS?

Comment: @shu Both of those achieve exactly the same thing. I prefer `.remove()` because it's more terse.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

oh ok. `it is ChildNode.remove()`, but it does remove the element itself not the child of the element.

Comment: It's still quite confusing since `object` can be `x` or the element. And also, if `this.btn` is not an html element then assigning `this.btn = null` can sometimes indeed remove the object from memory.

Comment: _"if `this.btn` is not an html element then assigning `this.btn = null` can sometimes indeed remove the object from memory."_ -- this statement is misleading in several ways. Whether or not `this.btn` is an element has no bearing on whether `this.btn = null` removes the object from memory. It only has the side-effect of doing so _if and only if_ it is the last reachable reference in the program to that object, and if you have something in your program that requires you to explicitly `null` a reference to garbage collect it, then you're most likely storing the reference in a sub-optimal scope.

Comment: @CertainPerformance by the way, calling `Node#remove()` does not remove any event listeners attached, so doing that alone _will not allow the element to be garbage collected_ unless everything that had access to the scope of the function for the event listener no longer has reachable references in the program.